# Autenticação django allauth

Tags: django

Criei uma autenticação de usuário com django allauth, funciona em partes, faz signup, login, fica salvo no admin tudo certo. Quando faço o cadastro do usuário e senha funciona perfeito, mas quando preencho usuário, e-mail e senha da erro na página. Já entendi que problema é no e-mail. Na configuração do settings.py deixei e-mail como opcional, já alterei várias vezes e nada. Alguém pode me ajudar?

**Abaixo o Settings.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'crispy_forms',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',

    'django.contrib.sites',

    'core.apps.CoreConfig',
    
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sos_pet.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sos_pet.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/login/"

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

]
```

**Abaixo a view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Pet
from .models import Usuario
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


def showcase(request):
    pet = Pet.objects.filter(active=True)
    return render(request, 'sos_pet/showcase.html', {'pet':pet})

def showdetail(request, id):
    pet = Pet.objects.get(active=True, id=id)
    return render(request, 'sos_pet/showdetail.html', {'pet':pet})


@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def set_pet(request):
    city = request.POST.get('city')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    phone = request.POST.get('phone')
    description = request.POST.get('description')
    file = request.FILES.get('file')
    user = request.user
    pet_id = request.POST.get('pet_id')
    if pet_id:
        pet = Pet.objects.get(id=pet_id)
        if user == pet.user:
            pet.email = email
            pet.phone = phone
            pet.city = city
            pet.description = description 
            if file:
                pet.photo = file
            pet.save()
    else:
        pet = Pet.objects.create(email=email, phone=phone, city=city, description=description,
                                user=user, photo=file)
    url = '/pet/detail/{}/'.format(pet.id)
    return redirect(url)

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def delete_pet(request, id):
    pet = Pet.objects.get(id=id)
    if pet.user == request.user:
        pet.delete()
    return redirect('/pet/all/')


@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def register_pet(request):
    pet_id = request.GET.get('id')
    if pet_id:
        pet = Pet.objects.get(id=pet_id)
        if pet.user == request.user:
            return render(request, 'sos_pet/register-pet.html', {'pet':pet})
    return render(request, 'sos_pet/register-pet.html')


@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def list_all_pets(request):
    pet = Pet.objects.filter(active=True)
    return render(request, 'sos_pet/list.html', {'pet':pet})

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def list_user_pets(request):
    pet = Pet.objects.filter(active=True, user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'sos_pet/list.html', {'pet':pet})

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def pet_detail(request, id):
    pet = Pet.objects.get(active=True, id=id)
    return render(request, 'sos_pet/pet.html', {'pet':pet})

def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/login/')

def login_user(request):
    return render(request, 'sos_pet/login.html')
    
@csrf_protect
def submit_login(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/pet/all/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Usuário/Senha inválidos. Favor tentar novamente.')
    return redirect('/login/')
```

**Abaixo o urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from core import views
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static, staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import settings
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.showcase),
    path('detail/<slug:id>/', views.showdetail),   
    path('login/', views.login_user),
    path('login/submit', views.submit_login),
    path('logout/', views.logout_user),
    path('pet/user/', views.list_user_pets),
    path('pet/all/', views.list_all_pets),
    path('pet/detail/<slug:id>/', views.pet_detail),
    path('pet/register/', views.register_pet),
    path('pet/register/submit', views.set_pet),
    path('pet/delete/<slug:id>/', views.delete_pet),

    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Erro apresentado**

```
ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/signup/

[Errno 111] Connection refused

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version:     3.1.3
Exception Type:     ConnectionRefusedError
Exception Value:    

[Errno 111] Connection refused

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py, line 796, in create_connection
Python Executable:  /home/luciano/project_sos_pet/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.8.5
Python Path:    

['/home/luciano/project_sos_pet',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/luciano/project_sos_pet/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 13 Jan 2021 18:47:19 +0000
```

Answer (score -1):

Achei a solução!!

**Adicionei no settings.py**

```
if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'
```